Convert pdf2html in React Js
"I am currently working on a project where I need to convert uploaded PDF files into HTML. To achieve this, I am using the pdf2html package. However, I am encountering an error during the conversion process. The specific error message.
enter image description here
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/majidkhan/Desktop/Projects/duralux/node_modules/gm'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
    enter code here

I have already installed this package.
My goal is to convert a PDF URL into HTML format. I have tried [mention any specific steps or approaches you've attempted], but I haven't been able to resolve the issue yet.
I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or solutions that could help me resolve this problem.

As the error message says:
webpack.config.js:
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify")
    },
  },
};

